# AWS SNS Invalid parameter: Name Reason: An application with the same name but different properties already exists

Tags: php, ios, laravel, amazon-web-services, push-notification

Trying to push notifications to iOS devices using [AWS SNS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/welcome.html), I created an application manually via AWS console and tried to access the ARN(Amazon Resource Name) by invoking [createPlatformApplication](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_CreatePlatformApplication.html).

Here's how I call the API using PHP:

```
$result = $client->createPlatformApplication(array(
            'Name' => 'MyApp',
            'Platform' => 'APNS_SANDBOX',
            'Attributes' => array(      
                'PlatformCredential' => '../myApp_key.pem', 
                'PlatformPrincipal' => '../myApp_cert.pem', 
            // these 2 files are same as the .pem files I uploaded to AWS creating the application
            ),

        ));
```

I supposed to get application ARN as return but got an error instead:

> InvalidParameterException in NamespaceExceptionFactory.php line 91:
>   Invalid parameter: Name Reason: An application with the same name but
>   different properties already exists

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try `'Name' => 'MyApp2'`

Comment: @vitr I don't want a new one but the existing app's arn. Any suggestion?

Comment: then don't call `createPlatformApplication` again, try something like `listPlatformApplications` and re-use existing app

Comment: @vitr that works fine! Is there a way to get a specific application arn based on provided .pem files?